# Does ganache only store the most recent transaction's events?

Tags: ganache

I can log them to the console in each transaction with subscribe, but the ganache UI only ever shows the latest one, as does `web3.eth.getPastLogs`.

Comment: I have tried asking this on the gitter multiple times but haven't heard back, so I am asking it here.

Comment: No, it should be storing all events. And if you use `web3.eth.getPastLogs` between 1 and latest, then you should be getting all of them (for a given address). If you only get 1 event, then it means that there was only 1 event.

Comment: My address is for a factory - when the factory creates a new contract, it emits an event. I just tried getPastLogs on it - when I call the create method to create child contract `C_i` and then call getPastLogs I see the new log `L_i ` corresponding to current block number `n`. When I then call it again to create child contract `C_j`, and call getPastLogs, I see a different log `L_j` for the block `n + 1`, and `L_i` is no longer present.